# Is skeuomorphism in web design considered old-fashioned nowadays?

Tags: website-design, design-principles

My CEO and his client expected me to copy the similar following site: http://grupoeuroquadros.com.br/.

But I do not want to do it. The site is skeuomorphic and old-fashioned. Observe the 3D gradient navbar and the steel background. Only Material Design is futuristic and modern.

I preferred developing my own project without skeuomorphism and following design principles. My CEO's client didn't like my Google Material Design project because he found it amateur, old-fashioned and unprofessional.

Are skeuomorphic web-designs (similar to the example site) considered old-fashioned nowadays? Is it possible for a skeuomorphic design to be modern and professional?

Comment: @Gustavo I've made some considerable edits to your question and reopened it. I removed the parts about plagiarism and your boss's attitude towards your design and focused on the skeuomorphism; those are really three separate issues, so please ask them as separate distinct questions if you'd like to. We really need focused distinct questions here so we can give clear and complete answers.

Comment: Did you try to develop a mood board for the site?

Comment: @Stan, I applied that style on my same project, without plagiarising, but the client didn't like either. He forced me to plagiarise the whole site, but I refused. I and my ex-CEO (I fired myself today) fired the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skeuomorphism is *not* "old fashioned", It's just no longer as "trendy". However, it is still *very* relevant.

There is a world of difference between "old fashioned' and "trendy".

The reality is skeuomorphism is still used, but in more subtle ways than previous iterations. Google's Material Design with the long shadows and ripple effects are skeuomorphism traits. In addition, gradients are a staple of all current trends... flat, material, etc. They are merely more subtle gradients than gradients used 10 years ago. That doesn't make them any less skeuomorphic.

Dismissing an entire design moment as "old fashioned" really only means you're set on following trends. Design has always been rooted in history. I have no clue where you get the impression that only Material Design is "modern". It's a trend like any other trend. It's **not** the only design style in existence. Pigeonholing into one style just means you'll be the last person standing in front of Blockbuster video waiting to rent a VHS tape while everyone else is streaming Netflix.

As for that particular site, my personal opinion is that I would *not* refer to it as skeuomorphic. Other than the gradients in the header, I see no indication of other skeuomorphic characteristics. And, as I've posted, gradients *are* still a staple of *all* current trends as far as I'm aware.

As for "copying the site". My experience tells me when a client requests something like this they are essentially telling you "I like this design style". Naturally you'd have to have a conversations to confirm this. However, generally they can't pinpoint *what* specifically speaks to them, only that they like the "mood" of the design. It's generally the "mood" I shoot for rather than replicating specific aspects directly.

Comment: Copying the site means plagiarising that site. He wanted that whole site because he found it beautiful, modern and professional.